# Joining 3 tables to return each user's questionnaires between two dates (my challenging query)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'll try to be brief and cut-to-the-chase as possible here.
These are my tables:

**questionnaire:**

- id[pk],
- name,
- type

**user_x_questionnaire:**

- id[pk],
- userid[fk],
- questionnaireid[fk references questionnaire.id]
- completedstate,
- iteration

**questionnaire_time**

- id[pk]
- questionnaireid[fk references questionnaire.id]
- iteration
- publishdate[date/time]
- deadline[date/time]

So, users want to fill out some questionnaires. Each user can be assigned to one or more that one questionnaire to fill (user_x_questionnaire). depending on the questionnaire type (one time or frequent) each questionnaire can be filled by the user more than once, therefore questionnaire_time table stores the publishdate and deadline of each of these times.

What I want is a query that displays all the current questionnaires that the user is supposed to answer. That means the time of the questionnaire should be between publishdate and deadline. I went very close to the answer of this query until I realized all my returned results produce the same publish and deadline which is not what I wanted. This is my solution so far.

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT questionnaire.id
        , questionnaire.`name`
        , user_x_questionnaire.iteration
        , completedstate
        , questionnaire_time.publishdate
        , questionnaire_time.deadline
   FROM user_x_questionnaire
      , questionnaire_time
      , questionnaire 
   WHERE  userid={USERID} 
      AND user_x_questionnaire.questionnaireid=questionnaire.id
      AND questionnaire.`type`='frequent' 
      AND user_x_questionnaire.questionnaireid=questionnaire_time.questionnaireid
   ) As result
WHERE '{CURRENT DATE}' BETWEEN publishdate AND deadline;
```

{USERID} and {CURRENT DATE} will be provided by the program.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: think i found the answer, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This should show all active questionnaries, even if not responded by the {USER}:

```
SELECT q.id, q.`name`, u.iteration, u.completedstate, t.publishdate, t.deadline
FROM questionnaire q
  INNER JOIN questionnaire_time t 
          ON t.questionnaireid = q.id
    LEFT JOIN user_x_questionnaire u 
           ON u.questionnaireid = t.questionnaireid
          AND u.userid={USERID} 
WHERE q.`type`='frequent' 
  AND '{CURRENT DATE}' BETWEEN t.publishdate AND t.deadline;
```

Comment: Thanks I'll check it this afternoon when I get home and will come back to you.

Comment: unfortunately it still shows the same dates for all the results. if there are three rows for the same questionnaire, the dates are still the same while they have different dates in questionnaire_time table.

Answer (score 0):

Finally!

```
select distinct q.id,
q.`name`,
uq.iteration,
completedstate,
qt.publishdate,
qt.deadline
from questionnaire_time qt,questionnaire q, user_x_questionnaire uq 
where qt.questionnaireid = q.id 
and qt.questionnaireid = uq.questionnaireid 
and uq.userid="{USERID}" 
and '{CURRENT DATE}' between qt.publishdate and qt.deadline 
group by q.id
```

Comment: Are you sure the `group by` is right?  Maybe it's not an issue, but note that this query doesn't return open questionnaires with no response yet.